# __init__ method runs multiple times

Tags: python, flask, import

Here is my (simplified) flask code

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from api_v1.api import api as api_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5001, debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

here is api.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, request
from api_v1.db.connect_db import Dbs


db = Dbs() api = Blueprint('api/v1/', __name__)
```

here is connect_db.py

```
import mysql.connector


class Dbs:
    def __init__(self):
        print("connecting")
        self.source_db = mysql.connector.connect(
            # credentials goes here
        )
        self.main_db = mysql.connector.connect(
           # credentials goes here
        )
        self.source_cursor = self.source_db.cursor()
        self.main_cursor = self.main_db.cursor()
        print("connected")
```

output:

> connecting

> connected

> - Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
> - Environment: production
>   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
>   Use a production WSGI server
>   instead.
> - Debug mode: on
> - Restarting with stat

> connecting

> connected

> - Debugger is active!
> - Debugger PIN: 000-00-000  *
>   Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

The problem is,
**THIS CONNECTS TWICE TO THE DATABASES**

And it's showing duplicate connections from the app in my mysql server

1. Why is this happening?
2. Anyone know a solution ?

Comment: `Restarting with stat`  - which part of your code is responsible for printing this message?

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5001, debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly connecting twice as in:

```
self.source_db = mysql.connector.connect(
            # credentials goes here
        )
self.main_db = mysql.connector.connect(
       # credentials goes here
    )
```

Connect once and then run USE db_name to change database
[MySQL Use statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html#:%7E:text=The%20USE%20statement%20tells%20MySQL%20to%20%20use,session%20or%20another%20USE%20statement%20is%20%20issued:)

Comment: I think the question is more about the fact that based on the output, the `__init__` seems to have run twice as both `connecting` and `connected` are printed twice.

Comment: Nope, they are two databases in two different servers.

Comment: set app.debug to False